# Get the name of the ion-select-option in ionic4

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am unable to get the name from the ion-select. I can able to get the value from the ion-select-option using the `[(ngmodel)]`. However i can able to find how to get the name from the selected ion-select-option.

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-select placeholder="Select User"  [(ngModel)]="selectedUser" (ionChange)="selectedUser1(selectedUser)" style="width:100%;max-width:100%;">              
          <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of user" value="{{item.pos_id}}">{{item.pos_name}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

I need to get the `{{item.pos_name}}` - name in the typescript variable.  Please help me to get the name of the selected ion-select-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 option: You can loop through your `User` array to find name and other info like.

```
selectedUser1(selectedUser){
 this.user.map(val, index){
   if(selectedUser == val.pos_id){
     console.log(val); // this will print your complete object of user.
  }
 }
}
```

2 option: Pass name as Value with your id.

`<ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of user" value="{{item.pos_id}}, {{item.pos_name}}">{{item.pos_name}}</ion-select-option>`
 you will get id and Name in your `selectedUser` ngModel. you can split it according to your need.